# Open supersets of dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $B \subset A$ be dense in $A$. Is the following true: For all open sets $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $B \subset G$ it follows that $A \subset G$.
It seems like it has to be true but I can't prove it. I've been struggling on the following part of my proof: pick $x \in A$ now pick some $y \in B$ such that $|x-y|< \epsilon_y$. Since $G$ is open there exists a $r_y > 0$ such that for all $z \in \mathbb{R}\colon |z-y|< r_y \Rightarrow z \in G$. Now I am struggling to show, that $|x-y|<r_y$. Even though $y$ can come as close as possible to $x$, meaning very small $\epsilon_y$ what if $r_y < \epsilon y$ for all $y \in B$?

Remark: I am considering the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Consider $B=G=(0,1)$ and $A =[0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false: consider $A = \mathbb{R}$, $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $G = B$.